# Getting Mutating trigger error while updating

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i am trying update lastupdate column when ever there is change in colB, but when i used below trigger i am getting mutating trigger error, i tried using compound trigger as well

```
 create or replace trigger LASTUPDATE_TRIG
 BEFORE update on TABLE_A

 referencing OLD as old NEW as new
 for each row WHEN (new.colB <> old.COLB)
 DECLARE

V_NUMBER NUMBER;
begin

V_NUMBER := :new.COLA;
update TABLE set LAST_UPDATE_DATE = sysdate where colA= v_number;
end;
```

Comment: it worked with below script

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LASTUPDATE_TRIG
        before INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON FQC_TABLE A
     referencing old as old new as new 
        for  each row 

        begin

            if :new.COLB <> :old.COLB and updating  then
             :new.COLC:=sysdate;
            end if;

    end;

Answer (score 1):

```
          CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LASTUPDATE_TRIG
    before INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON FQC_TABLE A
 referencing old as old new as new 
    for  each row 

    begin

        if :new.COLB <> :old.COLB and updating  then
         :new.LAST_UPDATE_DATE:=sysdate;
        end if;

end;
```

Comment: This; don't update the table again inside the trigger (that would cause a cascade, no?), update the pseudo table `:new`